# Converting .mvt file to .shp file

Tags: shapefile, convert, mapbox, vector-tiles

I managed to scrape an .mvt (mapbox vector tile) file from an online interactive map: [here](http://www.loginmumbai.org/). I procured a landuse development layer. What I want to do is, to reproject this to EPSG:4326 WGS 84 so that I can combine it with other mumbai shapefiles to create a landuse map with transport lines etc. From the site where I scraped, I am unable to get any projection information. Internet tells me that mapbox vector tiles usually use the EPSG:3857 projection, which I have tried to set in QGIS, but that appears to be incorrect too. I also cannot find any resources online to deal with converting the mvt geometry into coordinate systems.

Any tips?

I am new at this.  I have attached a sample .mvt file from the site [here](https://filebin.net/y5ifoyh4vjplw5tv) for reference.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: under the hood (ctrl+u) it states, .all,projection: 'EPSG:900913'